# I need to add an OBD-II based accessory to a OBD-port-less and ECU-less car

Tags: electrical, obd-ii, adapt

My guess is the accessory would work fine if only provided power (no need for it to receive diagnostics info, just to turn on to perform its function).

Would it be possible to connect pins 16 and 4 to battery and ground, respectively, to have the accessory turn on?

[image: OBD pins description]

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! If all you need is power and ground, 4/16 will do it for you. Are you looking at the above chart as though it is the connector of the device you are trying to power? If so, remember you have to turn it around as though you're looking at the above from the backside. Otherwise you're looking at 5/9 instead of 4/16. IOW, if you apply power to 16 and ground to 4, your device should power up, just ensure you're looking at it correctly when you do.